# Passing a Memory Stream from one API to another API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, export-to-excel, awss3transferutility

I am trying to export some data to excel and store that excel in AWS S3. Our current architecture is like,

1. we get data from database and manipulate it as per our needs. This is done is one API call.
2. We need to pass that data as stream to another API ( specifically designed to interact with AWS S3)
3. Store that stream as Excel file in AWS S3.

So far what i have achieved is :

I am able to get data from database and convert it to memory stream. I have written another API to receive this stream.  But couldn't manage to get to pass memory stream from one API to another API.

1st API :

```
    public async Task<ICollection<UserDTO>> ExportUsers(Guid groupId, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {

       var ms = // get's memory stream out of data received from database.

          var client = new HttpClient
                             {
                               BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58025/")
                             };
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

      MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter(); 
    //Not sure about BsonMediaTypeFormmater. Juz gave it a try

       var response = await  client.PostAsync("http://localhost:58025/Resource/Memory", ms, bsonFormatter);
    }
```

2nd API :

```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("Resource/Memory", Name = "UploadMemory")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadMemoryFile(MemoryStream memory)
   {
       // Not reaching until here
   }
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe this would be of help, http://www.andrescottwilson.com/posting-content-from-memory-stream-using-httpwebrequest-c/, but this uses Multipart/form-data and not bson

Comment: Make sure you also enable the BsonMediaTypeFormatter  on the server. Ref: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21